# Convert zeros into very small numbers

Tags: r

I have some data that i would like to take the log of and then make a heatmap of.  Heatmap is complaining because of the `-Inf` generated by the zeros in my data frame.

I would like to convert all of the zeros into very small numbers.  I think this should be relatively easy, but I am getting errors.  Eg.

```
Error in ifelse(ztest = 0, 1e-05, ztest) : unused argument(s) (ztest = 0)
```

Here is some example data:

```
 ztest<-data.frame(A=c(0,1,2,3),B=c(0,0,1,2),C=c(1,2,3,4))
```

Here are some of the attempts that I have made, they all complain about unused arguements, so I guess that I am not understanding how to write these functions correctly.  Although these attempts all look very similar to answers to similar questions posted on this site.

1. `z_inf <- ifelse(ztest=0,0.00001,ztest)`
2. `z[z=0]<-0.00001`
3. `inf_conv <- function(x){ifelse(x=0,0.00001,x)}
   z_inf<-apply(z,c(1,2),inf_conv)`

Comment: `?zapsmall` may be helpful ... also, you need `==` rather than `=` to test equality

Comment: You can't just add 1 to all values? Then  `log(z+1)=0` and remains interpretable.

Comment: thanks I thought it might be something simple

Comment: If it's not critical  that the heatmap be in logspace,  plot a heatmap of  `z^N` where `0 < N < 1` .  Problem solved.

Comment: There's also the log1p() and expm1() functions you might want to look at.

Answer (score 6):

So that you have more than comments, here's an edit to your attempt #2 which should do what you want:

```
z[z==0] <- .00001
```

You only had one '=' before, so it was trying to assign a value of 0 to data frame z, rather than subsetting the 0 values as you intended.